# How to change a key-value pair of a hash in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a query that returns an array and a hash.

How can I change the hash and add a new key-value pair to it: `import_id: 1, cost: 0`, or can I use a `map` method on the query?

The query is as follows.

```
name = Store.joins(:paid => :supply).group(:name).select("supply.name").where("stores.identifier IN (?) ", tids).pluck(:supply_id, :name)
```

The array is as follows.

```
[[258, "Square"], [245, "App"]]
```

When I convert it to a hash, it returns the following.

```
{258=>"Square", 245=>"App"}
```

The desired output is as follows.

```
{{supply_id: 258, name: "Square", import_id: 1, cost: 0}, {supply_id: 245, name: "App", import_id: 1, cost: 0}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the response is an array of `[supply_id, name]` pairs. You can easily destructure the array and restructure the data as hashes with proper symbolic keys.

```
array = [[258, "Square"], [245, "App"]]

array.map do |(id, name)|
  { supply_id: id, name: name, import_id: 1, cost: 0 }
end

# [{:supply_id=>258, :name=>"Square", :import_id=>1, :cost=>0}, ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `#select` instead of `#pluck` and call `.as_json` or `.map(&:attributes)`

```
Store.joins(:paid => :supply).group(:name)
  .select("supply.name").where("stores.identifier IN (?) ", tids)
  .select(:supply_id, :name).as_json

# [{supply_id: 258, name: "Square"}, {supply_id: 245, name: "App"}]
```

or

```
Store.joins(:paid => :supply).group(:name)
  .select("supply.name").where("stores.identifier IN (?) ", tids)
  .select(:supply_id, :name).map(&:attributes)

# [{supply_id: 258, name: "Square"}, {supply_id: 245, name: "App"}]
```

or you can construct Hash with `{import_id: 1, cost: 0}` appended

```
Store.joins(:paid => :supply).group(:name)
  .select("supply.name").where("stores.identifier IN (?) ", tids)
  .select(:supply_id, :name)
  .map {|e| {supply_id: e.supply_id, name: e.name, import_id: 1, cost: 0} }

# [{supply_id: 258, name: "Square", import_id: 1, cost: 0}, {supply_id: 245, name: "App", import_id: 1, cost: 0}]
```

or

You can use `Hash#merge` during Hash generation step to include `{import_id: 1, cost: 0}`

```
hash.merge({import_id: 1, cost: 0})

# To achieve: {{supply_id: 258, name: "Square", import_id: 1, cost: 0}, {supply_id: 245, name: "App", import_id: 1, cost: 0}}
```